# Select all columns except one when joining two tables in AWS Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, join, amazon-athena, presto

I want to join two large tables with many columns using Presto SQL syntax in AWS Athena. My code is pretty simple:

```
select
    * 
from TableA as A
left join TableB as B
on A.key_id = B.key_id
;
```

After joining, the primary key column (`key_id`) is repeated two times. Both tables have more than 100 columns, and the joining takes very long. How can I fix it such that the `key_id` column does not repeat twice in the final result?

P.S. AWS Athena does not support `except` command, unlike Google BigQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be a nice feature, but is not part of standard SQL. The `EXCEPT` keyword is a set-based operation (i.e. filtering rows).

In Athena, as with standard SQL, you will have to specify the columns you want to include. The argument for this is that it's lower maintenance, and in fact best practice is to always explicitly state the columns you want - never leaving this to "whatever columns exist". This will help ensure your queries don't change behaviour if/when your table structure changes.

Some SQL languages have features like this. I understand Oracle has this too. But to my knowledge Athena (/ PrestoSQL / Trino) does not.

Answer (score 3):

Athena does have a similar function, but it's slightly more complex to use.
See https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/table.html

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE(exclude_columns(
                  input => TABLE(orders),
                  columns => DESCRIPTOR(clerk, comment)
           ) 
      )
```

For your example:

```sql
 with 
    table_a as (select 1 as a1, 2 as a2, 3 as key),
    table_b as (select 1 as b1, 2 as b2, 3 as key),
    joined as (
        select *, table_a.key as a_key
        from table_a 
        join table_b on table_a.key = table_b.key
 )
 select a_key as key, *
 from 
    TABLE(
        exclude_columns(
                        input => TABLE(joined),
                        columns => DESCRIPTOR(key)
                        )
        )
```